# Reset buttons images on WinForms

Tags: winforms

The button's images are binded to the resource, like this:

```
btnCancel.BackgroundImage = Localization.Labels.cancel;
```

And depending on culture desired image is selected. But culture could be changed while runtime and button's images should be reseted depending on new selected culture.

Of cause I could just copy the same like of code in redraw method, but there are lots of controls, and I'm looking for more elegant way.

Comment: Did you try something like `this.Update();` and `this.Refresh();`?

Comment: yes, but with no success

Comment: Then you should copy the code and use it everytime you need it. Don't forget `this.SuspendLayout();` and `this.ResumeLayout();`

Comment: Thanks! Any other ideas?